# Solr French ontology

Tags: solr, ontology

I want to ask how to implement French ontology like "WOLF" in my solr search engine.
The idea is, when I search for term "voiture" to give me also results like "car" "wagon" "auto".

So far i have indexed my data and implement some plugins in my search engine ( like stemming, spellchecker ..), it works perfectly.

I plan to do at like this,
Index all WOLF ontology in the same solr with my data collection,

so when I search for some term I will query solr-WOLF data, to retrieve synonyms,

localhost:8983/solr/wolf/spell1?q=words%3A($query);

and than make another query to the real data,

localhost:8983/solr/data/spell1?q=groupe%3A($query,$term1, $term2);

to display the results.

Is this possible ?
Can I use some other approach, way or something ?
Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is certainly possible, although possibly less efficient than using Solr's built in [synonym filter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory). Additionally you have to be careful at query time since in some cases (especially biomedical, I've noticed) the query expansion will be very large, greatly slowing down response time.

You could serialize your ontology's synonyms into Solr's synonym format and then use that to add synonyms at index time.

This, of course, doesn't deal with the fact that you may want to utilize the structure of your ontology during your queries (ie search for all "sub-parts" of a transmission), which is a different question entirely.

Comment: OK, tnx for the answer, I will try with synonym filter .